# Adding constraint in the EMP table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to add a constraint in the EMP table in Oracle so that the hiredate field can not be sunday?

Comment: Have you made any attempt?  This is not particularly difficult.  Hint:  `alter table`, `to_char()`.

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do it using the `CHECK` constraint within the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
SQL> create table test (
  2    id        number,
  3    hiredate  date constraint ch_hd check
  4                     (to_char(hiredate, 'dy', 'nls_date_language=english') <> 'sun')
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> -- Tuesday - should be OK
SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2018-02-13');

1 row created.

SQL> -- Sunday - should fail
SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2018-02-18');
insert into test values (1, date '2018-02-18')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_HD) violated


SQL>
```

If your table already exists, you'd have to add a new constraint using the `ALTER TABLE` statement (as you've already been suggested). Try, say if you can't make it work.